# Run windows from from asp.net app and pass data back to asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I am developing a personal project. What I am planning to do is, from a ASP.NET application on a button click I want to launch a windows form application on client machine (the .exe of windows form will be pre-loaded to client machine).

This windows form will read a COM port where a RFID reader is connected.

After launching windows from on client machine, windows form will read RFID and pass the data back to my ASP.NET application.

Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Challenges I have are:
1. How to launch win form on client machine from a button click on ASP.NET web application.?
2. Once my wiform reads the RFID reader, how can I pass that value back to my asp.net application?

Comment: You need to focus on one problem at a time, otherwise your question becomes too broad. As for how to launch an app on a client machine - you know how to write an app that runs on a client machine right? And you know how to make it talk to a server? And you know how to launch a Windows Forms application from an app running on the machine? Then you know everything you need to handle that part. Focus on the specific bits you don't know how to do.

Comment: I have built an ASP app and from that app on a button click I can open a windows form now. Here is the code
` var appLocation = @"C:\RFIDReader\bin\Debug\RFIDReader.exe";
            Process test = new Process();
            test.StartInfo.FileName = appLocation;
test.Start();` 
but this asp app and winform both are in my local machine.

Comment: Cool. So now you need that app to launch the other when triggered to do so by the web app. You could poll the server (send an HTTP request every few seconds) and ask the server if it needs to launch the RFIDReader.exe. Or you could use a library like SignalR to push a notification from the web server to the launcher app. You need to research those approaches, pick one, and try it out. If you get stuck with your implementation, create a [MCVE].